# Gitlab: unable to pull image from docker hub?

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd, dockerhub

I am trying to build a docker image for my application inside docker container, this is example of docker insider docker concept.

I am trying to pull docker image, here is the yaml code for my gitlab job

```
build_image:
  image: docker:20:10:17
  services:
    - docker:20.10.17-dind
  variables:
   DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Every time the pipeline runs it shows this error

```
Pulling docker image docker:20:10:17 ...
WARNING: Failed to pull the image with policy "always": invalid reference format (manager.go:235:0s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "docker:20:10:17" with specified policies [always]: invalid reference format (manager.go:235:0s)
```

Note:- I am using the managed runner on gitlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using colons here: `docker:20:10:17`

but you should be using dots: `docker:20.10.17`

Comment: Thanks @ericfossas for pointing out a minute but important detail